# Generate Java code given a diagram PlantUML

Tags: java, diagram, plantuml

I need to research about UML Tool PlantUML for presentation. And I use plugins `plantUML integration` in Intellij, here is my text to draw diagram

```
class Bird
interface Flying {
{abstract} flying(): void
}
abstract class Animal {
- name: String
+ getName(): String
}
Bird --|> Animal
Bird ..|> Flying
```

This is my diagram image

[image]

How can I generate Java code from the diagram?

Comment: @user16320675 thanks, bro. I have already edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s not the way PlantUML or the PlantUML integration plugin works. PlantUML is about creating diagrams via text, not about Model-Driven Development.

You should be looking for something that supports you doing Model-Driven Development. I know of

- Eclipse Modeling Framework
- ArgoUML
- Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect
- IBM Rational Rose

You‘ll have to search for such tools.

Comment: Hi, can you explain for me why PlantUML not work